# XPATH extract text within <br>

Tags: xpath

I am practicing with XPATH to extract text within HTML.

I have the following structure:

```
<tbody>
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td class="table-cell">
        Name
        <br />
        Address
        <br />
        Postcode
        <br />
        Phone: 111111
        <br />
        Fax:  123456
        <br />
        Email:  <a class="mail" href="mailto:mail@example.com">mail@example.com</a>
        <br />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td class="table-cell">
        Name
        <br />
        Address
        <br />
        Postcode
        <br />
        Phone: 111111
        <br />
        Fax:  123456
        <br />
        Email:  <a class="mail" href="mailto:mail@example.com">mail@example.com</a>
        <br />
    </td>
  </tr>
  (...)
</tbody>
```

I manage to navigate different nodes but I can't figure out how to extract within a text node.

In particular, I need to extract text within "Phone:" and following `<br />` and "Email:" and following `<br />` in all rows in the table.

Comment: Please show the XPath you have tried.. Do you also need the `<br />`s or just the texts?

Answer (score 1):

how about `//td/text()[4]` for Phone and `//td/a` for the email value